# How can I hide the chapter headings number on LaTeX and change the spacing?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I'm writing my Thesis but I have run into some layout troubles, I'm using the standard book document class, which results in my Chapters headings in the form of:

> Chapter #
>
> Name of my chapter

I was looking for a way to change it, removing the "Chapter #" from it to the form of:

> Name of my chapter

I have tried doing what I wanted with the following code on my main file, although I don't know if it is ideal, like I said in the comments I have tried with the /titlesec but I couldn't remove the chapter number:

```
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\hrule                                        % horizontal line
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Huge \scshape #1\par                        % chapter title
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\hrule                                        % horizontal rule
\nobreak
\vskip 2\baselineskip
}}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\hrule                                        % horizontal line
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Huge \scshape #1\par                         % chapter title
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\hrule                                        % horizontal line
\nobreak
\vskip 2\baselineskip
}}
```

I also need to set the spacing after the chapter heading to two lines as it's one of the requirements from my university, I'm currently trying to do it with the `\vskip #\baselineskip` but I'm getting a bigger spacing than the one I wanted so I'm guessing it has to do with the `\Huge` format modifier I used but I'm not sure.

Comment: Everything you want to do *can* be done with the `titlesec` package.  Can you show us what you've tried (with a small working example document.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). And as AlannMunn pointed out, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: the `amsbook` class *does* put starred chapters into the table of contents.  the overall style is somewhat different from that of the `book` class though, so it may not fill other requirements.  the major sectioning *commands* are essentially the same as for `book` so you might be able to try it out just by changing the `\documentclass`.

Comment: I'm using the book class since I wanted to use chapters and the /fontmatter /mainmatter get the format according with my university requirements, I haven't read much about other classes apart for the standard ones, as I just started using LaTeX a couple of days ago.

Comment: @AlanMunn I tried using titlesec and I successfully the "Chapter" word but I couldn't find a way to remove the chapter number from the heading.

Comment: If you're trying to match university requirements and you've just started using LaTeX, I would *strongly* recommend using the `memoir` class as a base. It is extremely well documented, and gives you fine control over almost everything you would need to satisfy the requirements. Otherwise you may find yourself with a series of hacked together code that you don't understand.

Comment: @SergioS. I've updated my answer below with a new suggestion for your code; notice that the code you just posted has additional modifications that you didn't mention in your question: you only mentioned suppressing some elements, but actually you also added some rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; setting the value of `\aftertitleunit` to `\baselineskip`, you can then use `*2` in the fourth mandatory argument of `\titlespacing` to obtain the desired vertical spacing between the title and the following text. You didn't provide information on the spacing before the title so I used `50pt`, but you can change this value to the one that best suits your needs. To maintain consistency between the numbered and unnumbered chapters I used two `\titleformat` commands with similar settings: one for the numbered chapters and another one, using the `numberless` key, for the unnumbered ones:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength\aftertitleunit{\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{*2}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Numbered chapter}
\chapter*{Test Unumbered chapter}

\end{document}
```

Taking into account the edit to the original question, you can add `\normalsize` just before `\vskip2\baselineskip`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\hrule                                        % horizontal line
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Huge \scshape #1\par                        % chapter title
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\hrule                                        % horizontal rule
\nobreak\normalsize
\vskip 2\baselineskip
}}

\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright
\normalfont
\hrule                                        % horizontal line
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\interlinepenalty\@M
\Huge \scshape #1\par                         % chapter title
\vspace{5pt}%                                 % add vertical space
\hrule                                        % horizontal line
\nobreak\normalsize
\vskip2\baselineskip
}}
\makeatother
```

And here's the same layout but using `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength\aftertitleunit{\baselineskip}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge \scshape}{\titlerule}{-33pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{-4pt}\titlerule]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge \scshape}{\titlerule}{-33pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{-4pt}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{*2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that last piece of code was the thing I wanted to do from the beginning but I couldn't figure out from the `/tittlesec` documentation, just out of curiosity how did you get the values in pt to use in your code?

Answer (score 5):

You state that you need to suppress the `Chapter <x>` line in a (numbered) chapter's header area. This change can be brought about by redefining the LaTeX command `\@makechapterhead` (set up in `book.cls`) to act exactly like `\@makeschapterhead`, which LaTeX employs to typeset the caption of unnumbered or "starred" chapters.

A second requirement you mention is having an amount of vertical whitespace equal to two blank lines between the chapter's header line and subsequent material. Not knowing the font size and line spacing settings of your documents, I'm afraid it's not possible to give a definitive setting here. In the example below, I use a skip value of `1\baselineskip`; you'll probably have to experiment a bit in order to find the value that's suitable to your institution's requirements.

I suggest you use the LaTeX package `etoolbox` and its command `\patchcmd` to modify the command `\@makeschapterhead`, as is done in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum} % use lipsum for filler text
\makeatletter
  % patch the command \@makeschapterhead
  \patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}{}{}
  % make \@makechapterhead act like \@makeschapterhead
  \let\@makechapterhead\@makeschapterhead 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1-5]
\mainmatter
\chapter{On a very fine day}
\lipsum[6-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A redefinition of `\@makeschapterhead` will possibly also be needed to guarantee the same spacing between the heading and the text for starred chapters.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- good point about possibly redefining the command `\@makeschapterhead` as well in order to keep the overall appearance of the two types of chapter heads consistent. I'll provide an addendum to explain how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using titlesec to change the chapter tittle but I couldn't remove the chapter number, I just started using LaTeX 2 days ago. Finally I used \renewcommand{\@makechapterhead} to get what I wanted, although I don't know if the correct way to do it. I'm using Arial with the fontspec package in size 12 with one half spacing, but I don't know how to calculate de space needed in pt units for that.

Comment: @SergioS. you don't need to know the value in `pt`. As Mico and I have shown in our answers, you can use the appropriate multiple (2 in your concrete case) of `\baselineskip` (the "distance" between the bases of two consecutive lines).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks I used `\vskip 2\baselineskip` but the resulting spacing is bigger than the one I need, It appear as if the /baselineskip is using the text size used for the headings (Huge) instead of the one I used for the normal text 12. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SergioS.: without seeing your actual code is almost impossible to give proper advise; please add to your question a minimal version of your actual code, showing the relevant current settings.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I added the code I'm using for the headings, thanks for the help.