# Custom Chapter Headings

Tags: titlesec

I am a Latex novice and am trying to use a template for formatting a novel I wrote. The template uses titlesec but I never title my chapters. In fact, I want my chapter headings in this book to be 'Day 0' and 'Day 1'. But the chapters also will skip days. 'Day 2' is followed by 'Day 4'. Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: `\chapter*{Day 2} ... \chapter*{Day 4}` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Unfortunately, this is probably not enough information, could you include some code that shows your problem please? Starting with your `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. It helps people help you, helps understand your problem and makes it faster for you `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, half an hour of googling didn't help, but the 'Related' answers did.
[How can I hide the chapter headings number on LaTeX and change the spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47953/how-can-i-hide-the-chapter-headings-number-on-latex-and-change-the-spacing?rq=1)
This was exactly what I needed.